# Error converting numeric only text string to int in SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm having a problem converting a number stored as a varchar to an int or decimal using the cast or convert function.

All other research I have done on this error suggests I must have non numeric characters in my text string, but as far as I am aware there are only valid numeric characters.

I have had to import numbers as a string from a csv file with double quotes, such as "202,918".

I have then updated the table to add a new column removing the comma and double quotes to get a text string of 202918 using:

```
UPDATE dbo.Table_Name
SET New_column = replace(replace(Original_column,'"',''),',','')
```

This is giving me the following data:

New_column 202918 243813 962 11335 6108 2106 3 2 614 263 468124

I am then trying to convert this to numeric value using

```
select cast([New_column] AS int) from dbo.Table_Name
```

and getting

> ```
> Syntax error converting the nvarchar value '202918
> ' to a column of data type int.
> ```

or

```
select cast([New_column] AS decimal(20,0)) from dbo.Table_Name
```

and getting

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Please can anybody help?

Comment: First one doesnt say you cant convert,it says syntax error.Post your query entirely

Comment: The data is being stored in a table called dbo.Table_Name in a column called New_column. My query is select cast(New_column AS int) from dbo.Table_Name

Answer (score 0):

This is giving me the following data:

New_column 202918 243813 962 11335 6108 2106 3 2 614 263 468124

the above data has spaces.Try like below

```
declare @string nvarchar(max)
set  @string=replace(' 202918 243813 962',' ','')
select convert(bigint,@string)
```

Answer (score 0):

The New_column value might have char(13) or char(10), remove them first.

```
UPDATE dbo.Table_Name
SET New_column = replace(replace(replace(replace(Original_column,'"',''),',',''),char(13),''),char(10),'')
```